# How can we migrate from digite project management tool to team foundation server

Tags: svn, tfs, jira

We are working in a project in which all the project related data i.e. Change Request, Defect, Issues, Documents, Daily time-sheet, Workflows etc. are maintained in the digite whereas svn is used as source safe for code checkout and checkin. Now my company wish to discontinue digite and looking for some other options for handling all this data and documents.

We have option of either using JIRA OR TFS out of which We would like to use the TFS more but the challenge is we are working digite for almost 8 years and there is so much data and documents which we still need in future so  how can we migrate those details from digite to TFS.

Answer (score 0):

There ins't a way or tool can migrate smoothly with the details from digite to TFS.

Seems you can only add the project or any other data itself to source control in TFS, but can not keep the details such as history...

However based on the description here :[Integrations with SwiftSync](https://www.digite.com/swiftsync/swiftsync-integration-platform/),

> SwiftSync is support integrations with popular tools such as TFS,
>   JIRA, CA Agile Central and many others. Using SwiftSync it is possible
>   to visualize work across the organization, through an eco-system of
>   tools.
>
> SwiftKanban lets you export work items or backlog to a file so you can
>   edit it in Excel and import cards in XLS format from other
>   applications into our project. You can even export your project
>   details to an Excel file if you want to share or view it someday.

So, you can have a try for it.